# How do I make my nodeJS server "remember" a particular user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, jwt, backend

I am currently developing a mobile application that uses Flutter for the front-end and NodeJS for the back-end. Things are going great but I am stuck on how to implement a sort of lottery feature.

I basically want the server to choose at random a user. Once this is done, the user will receive a token on his next post request which will alert him that he has been chosen. From this point on any post request that the user has to the server will come with his token, granting him special benefits.

My problem comes with the last part. How can I easily check on the server side, if the token received is the most recent one? as other users might make requests with older tokens from the earlier lotteries.

I think I should use a JWT authentification, but not every token expires at the same time and I don't know how to check if the received JWT is the most recent one.

I would prefer to not store the winner in a different database, as that would mean too many operations and it would be too slow.

Comment: You can use the redis cache for the node.js and update the token every time u generate a new token. Redis cache is fast and efficient. If you want to store it on server level, u can maintain a cache and override it every time u get a new token, but storing on server level is not advised as you will lose the token when the server restarts or deployed over multiple instances

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can't. It's logically not possible to have a client state that depends on other clients.

You can either work with a server state, that is keep the state of what user is the current chosen one in a regular DB (that you of course can cache for faster access).

Or you can work with a client state, where the client is obligated to keep the state in for example a JWT. (The JWT is signed so that the client cannot alter the state.) **But the client state cannot be affected by the state of other clients.** So they you would need a server state anyway, to either keep track of what client is the chosen one, or a blacklist of old winner tokens, or any other design you like, but it must end up being stored in the backend. (Unless you use a blockchain. ;-) )